# Absolute value of first derivative interpretation, why is this true?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives

in my book I have this:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$, and $x_0$ a point in which $f'(x_0) \ne 0$

Then

$\lim_{\delta\to0}$  $\frac{\mu( f([x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta ] )}{\mu( [x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta ])} = |f'(x_0)| $

Where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I feel pretty OK with that considering that the first derivative should measure the rate of change of the function in relation with the rate of change of the independent variable but why that's the exact expression formalizing this concept?

Comment: Is $\mu$ supposed to more specifically be Lebesgue measure?  This certainly isn't true for an arbitrary measure.

Comment: @EricWofsey I had the strong suspect that $\mu$ was the Lebesgue measure but I wasn't completely sure, so I avoided to specify. I edit the text-

Comment: do you know what $\mu( [x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta ])$ means and how to calculate it?

Comment: @user190080 It is a real interval so (correct me if I'm wrong) its Lebesgue measure should be $2\delta$...

Comment: No need for a correction, that's it - Eric's answer shows pretty nicely how straight forward some proofs are...sometimes it is really just plug-in

Comment: I'm not sure why the condition $f'(x_0)\ne0$ is there. Result is true in the case( $f'(x_0)=0$  as well.

Comment: @zhw I don't really know why, I just copy-pasted from my book. This example is used for an unidimensional intuition of the absolute value of the Jacobian's determinant if this could be somehow useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost literally just a rephrasing of the usual definition of the derivative.  If $f'(x_0)\neq 0$, then $f$ is monotonic in a neighborhood of $x_0$; let's assume it's increasing.  Then $f([x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta])$ is just the interval $[f(x_0-\delta),f(x_0+\delta)]$, so we are taking the limit of $$\frac{\mu([f(x_0-\delta),f(x_0+\delta)])}{\mu([x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta])}=\frac{f(x_0+\delta)-f(x_0-\delta)}{2\delta}.$$
This is just like the difference quotient defining $f'(x_0)$, except that we are taking a "two-sided" difference where we compare $f(x_0+\delta)$ and $f(x_0-\delta)$ instead of comparing each of them to $f(x_0)$.  Indeed, we can break this fraction up as $$\frac{f(x_0+\delta)-f(x_0-\delta)}{2\delta}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{f(x_0+\delta)-f(x_0)}{\delta}+\frac{f(x_0-\delta)-f(x_0)}{-\delta}\right)$$ which is just an average of two difference quotients (one for $h=\delta$ and one for $h=-\delta$).  So, since each difference quotient is converging to $f'(x_0)$, so is our fraction.

(If $f$ is decreasing instead of increasing, we get essentially the same thing except with a minus sign since $f$ reverses the order of the endpoints of our interval, so we get $-f'(x_0)=|f'(x_0)|$.)

Comment: I think this one is pretty clean, thanks for the answer.